# "Inheritance" Attribute: what does it do?

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes

I happened across an attribute in c# that's called `[Inheritance]`. Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inheritanceattribute.aspx) on the attribute is somewhat limited. The attribute has only one property which is an enumeration they call [inheritance level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inheritancelevel.aspx). That's about all I could find by googling about. So here are my questions:

- Does the attribute actually do anything or is it just a notation?
- If it does do anything, does it enforce inheritance (or lack thereof) by throwing a compile time error?
- Or, can it actually change what IS inherited? ex) `InheritanceLevel.NotInherited` is selected, does it then cancel out inheritance?

Comment: See remarks.  It has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: When do attributes ever _do_ anything, in and of themselves? They're  metadata to _do_ something _with_.

Comment: The doc mentions "When the AddInheritedComponents method of the IInheritanceService searches the component fields of a component to identify fields that are inherited from a base class, the method represents the inheritance level of each component using an InheritanceAttribute." That really doesn't say much, but I can say it's not used for anything but that.

Comment: It's easy to forget that attributes are _only_ metadata. That's something to which I'll have to pay more attention. As for the remarks section... I'm really glad they're people like you all on SO. **Really** glad.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: There are attributes that do things within the compiler (various interop things, `[MethodImpl]`, etc)

Comment: @SLaks That's the compiler taking the privilege of doing something with the indicators, not the metadata taking it upon itself to do anything, except 'be there'.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: Can't you say that about any piece of code? </pedant>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It does not do anything, it is a notation used internally by the compiler / linker
- N/A
- N/A